# DOMXpath query to get the value of a tag after a specific text

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I need a DOMXpath query to get the value of a tag after a specific text.
Here is my code but its not working

```
$str= '...............
URL: <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">http://example.com#showtext</a>
            ....................
 ';

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML($str);

    $xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $links = $xp->query('//[text()="URL: "]following-sibling::a[1]');

    foreach ($links as $link) {
    echo $link->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;

    }
    ?>
```

should I use following-sibling in my query or what it should be ?

Comment: also tried $links = $xp->query('//[text()="URL: "]/a'); but its not working too...

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a tag that follows a text node, so basically your xpath query must look like this:

```
//text()/following-sibling::node()
```

Then you add conditions:

```
//text()[contains(., "URL: ")]/following-sibling::node()[1][name(.)="a"]
```

The condition for the text node only checks if it contains `"URL: "` but you can be more explicit. If you want the text node to be exactly `"URL: "` write `[.="URL: "]` as condition.

If you want the text node ends with `"URL: "`, it is more difficult because xpath doesn't have an `ends-with` function. So you must write it in PHP, and [register](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registerphpfunctions.php) it yourself. Example:

```
function ends_with($node, $needle){
    return substr($node[0]->nodeValue, -strlen($needle)) === $needle;
}

$xp->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
$xp->registerPHPFunctions("ends_with");

$links = $xp->query('//text()[php:function("ends_with", ., "URL: ")]/following-sibling::node()[1][name(.)="a"]');
```

About the conditions for the second part of the xpath query:

`following-sibling::` targets not only the first node but all the nodes after. So writing `following-sibling::a[1]` returns that first "a" node after the text, without warranty that this node immediately follows the text.

To be sure that the first node after is an "a" tag, you need to target the first node after and to check it is an "a" tag with a condition:

`following-sibling::node()[1][name(.)="a"]`

Comment: Thanks. But I need href value... this code it work great //text()[contains(., "URL: ")]/following-sibling::node()[1][name(.)="a"] but it return http://example.com#showtext while I need http://www.example.com.

Comment: @pco: I'm wondering you didn't take the time to read an xpath tutorial nor a DOMDocument tutorial (5 minutes to solve your problem). As an aside you never asked about the href attribute in your question but "the value of a tag", so that is exactly what my code does.